# -y C command in iperf 2.0.5 doesn't work in the server side

Tags: client, client-server

I'm trying to use -y C command in iperf which is used to write the throughput between the client and server in CSV format. So this is the command that is used to start the server

```
            iperf -s -w 8M -f m -i 10 -p 4 // This works
```

But when i use the -y C which writes the output to in CSV format. The server doesn't start listening

```
           iperf -s -w 8M -f m -i 10 -p 4 -y C // This doesn't work.
```

i dont know why this is not working. But the same -y C on the client seems to be working.The answers are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Server is in Listening Mode. Try to send some data to the server. You will see data received on Server in CSV Format.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your command on my computer and I think there's a typo. You are setting the port to 4 (-p 4) which is one of the reserved ports (although wikipedia say [it's unassigned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers).

If I change your command to:

```
iperf -s -w 8M -f m -i 10 -P 4 -yc
```

it works (assuming you meant to have 4 threads), although it won't dump the output until the 10 second interval is over.